# Resizing a QWindow to fit contents

Tags: pyqt5, qt5

The main window of my PyQt5 application is set up with a text label along the top above a custom canvas widget which displays an image:

```py
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Canvas(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = None

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        qp = QtGui.QPainter(self)
        if self.image:
            qp.drawImage(0, 0, self.image)


class Window(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.canvas = Canvas()

        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        self.label.setText('foobar')
        self.label.setSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding,
                                QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed)

        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.label)
        layout.addWidget(self.canvas)
        layout.setSpacing(0)
        layout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)

        content = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        content.setLayout(layout)
        self.setCentralWidget(content)

        self.load_image('a.jpg')

    def load_image(self, filename):
        image = QtGui.QImage(filename)
        self.canvas.image = image
        self.canvas.setFixedSize(image.width(), image.height())
        self.update()

    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        self.load_image('b.jpg')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

This looks like this, which is what I want:

[image]

When the canvas changes to display a smaller image, I want to shrink the window to fit accordingly. However, it looks like this:

[image]

It seems that the minimum size that I can give the window if I manually drag to resize it *is* the size that fits the contents, but why isn't it resizing to this automatically?

Comment: @eyllanesc Ok, I updated the code sample.

Comment: When you load the image you can .resize(width, height) the window to that of the image you might have to maybe add a bit to compensate for the window versus the image size but once you have that figured out those dimensional differences (if any) ought to be a fairly static number.

Comment: @DennisJensen I don't think that's a great way to do it, because the value will differ on different operating systems.

Comment: @rgov as would the window's size?  You said you want the window to match the size of the object which means (1) You have to have the size of the object (2) You have to size the Window accordingly -- that said you write a function to handle that. Yes it might differ from OS to OS but frankly you code for that -- how do you think all those other libraries do it -- someone coded somewhere the (if on this OS do this else if on this OS do that else etc...)

Comment: @DennisJensen One shouldn't make assumptions about control sizes, for instance the system font size can change—the user may have accessibility needs, or the font may change (macOS recently changed system font). The window padding and spacing between objects should be vended by OS APIs. Qt's value is handling these details for you across platforms.

Comment: @rgov right and if I recall correctly you have access to that information from within Qt so you just have to reference it -- you do not have to go and vet it yourself that was not what I said.  Now if there is some slick way to get a window to conform to an object you give it cool but I have looked at the cascading Widgets and I have not seen anything like that within that classes layers.  Of course you could go with the other suggestion which is to change the size of your image to match the window.

Answer (score 2):

When a fixed size is set, it is used as sizeHint, and the latter is used by layouts to set the widget size. So the size of the canvas depends on the size of the widget, but you want the opposite. You must scale the image size to the window size:

```py
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Canvas(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setSizePolicy(
            QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding
        )
        self.image = QtGui.QImage()

    @property
    def image(self):
        return self._image

    @image.setter
    def image(self, image):
        self._image = image
        self.update()

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        qp = QtGui.QPainter(self)
        if not self.image.isNull():
            image = self.image.scaled(
                self.size(), QtCore.Qt.IgnoreAspectRatio, QtCore.Qt.SmoothTransformation
            )
            qp.drawImage(0, 0, image)


class Window(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.canvas = Canvas()

        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel("foobar")
        self.label.setSizePolicy(
            QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed
        )

        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.label)
        layout.addWidget(self.canvas)
        layout.setSpacing(0)
        layout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)

        content = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        content.setLayout(layout)
        self.setCentralWidget(content)

        self.load_image("a.jpg")

    def load_image(self, filename):
        image = QtGui.QImage(filename)
        self.canvas.image = image

    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        self.load_image('b.jpg')
        super().keyPressEvent(event)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution, but I would rather the window adopt the size of the image, rather than scale the image to the window. Is that possible?